# Why integrate of metrics and not inverse metrics?

Tags: quantum-gravity, path-integral

In quantum gravity it is generally said that the partition function is written as:

$$ Z[J] = \int e^{ i S[g] +J.g } D[g] $$

My question is why do we functionally integrate over all possible metrics and not, for example, all possible inverse metrics? The action can equally well be written in terms of the inverse of the metric. Just using the identity:

$$ g_{\mu \nu}(x) \equiv  \frac{1}{4! \det(g)}\varepsilon_{\mu bcd} \varepsilon_{\nu pqr}g^{bp}(x)g^{cq}(x)g^{dr}(x) $$

Or for that matter any other function of the metric?

Is it equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed. It's just not terribly interesting because for the most part, most terms of the action are written with the metric.